# R - Change function environment

Tags: r

I am a new user of R and I would like to know if it's possible to do that :

```
a = 2                     <environment: R_GlobalEnv>

f <- function(){
  x = 1
  y = 1
  g()
}                         <environment: 0xf1b79b8>

g <- function(){
  z = x + y + a
}                         <environment: 0xf1b7a98>
```

> ```
> Error in g() : object 'x' not found
> ```

Question : Is it possible to create a `g()` personalised access to Global and `f()` environment ?

Comment: Mmh, not clear what you want to accomplish... anyway you could define `g` function inside `f` function...

Comment: I would like to know if g() can access to variables from GlobalEnv and tempEnv from f() ?

Comment: why not just have g(x,y)?

Comment: Without a lot more context for why you're doing this, R programmers are likely to see this question as analogous to "Can I open this can of peaches with my jackhammer?". The answer is probably yes, but....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If just want the function to be able to get variables from the parent frame or, if not found, from the global environment, this should work (even if I discourage it *) :

```
g <- function(env=parent.frame()){
  z = get("x",envir=env) + get("y",envir=env) + get("a",envir=env)
  return(z)
}
```

So, this works :

```
rm(list=ls(pattern='[^g]')) # to be sure the global env is empty except for g function
a = 2                     

f <- function(){
  x = 1
  y = 1
  return(g())
} 

f()
# returns 4
```

**(*) I discourage this for mainly two reasons:**

1. The code is not very readable, and is not immediately clear what `g` does and where it takes `x`,`y` and `a`.
2. From a functional programming perspective, a good practice is to make functions as "self-contained" as possible (i.e. not relying on external/global variables) and as "stateless" as possible (i.e. not keeping any "state" when called). It's much better to pass what a function needs through its arguments, and let the function be just something that receives an input (through parameters), manipulates it, and returns an output.

Comment: Why is it dangerous to define other environment ?

Comment: We're nor defining environments here, we're just not using the default ones...but the reasons I discourage this approach is not for the environments but for what I've added in the bottom of the answer ;)

Answer (score 5):

One way to do this is to define `g()` *inside* `f()`:

```
a <- 2

f <- function(){
    g <- function(){
       z <- x + y + a
   }    
   x <- 1
   y <- 1
   g()
}

print(f())  ## 4
```