# How to define a variable within a function and use it to call another function

Tags: r, function

I want to define a variable within a function and use it when calling another function.
Let's consider following example:

```
my.func1 <- function(x){a*x^2}

temp.variable <- 2

my.func2 <- function(x){
  a <- temp.variable
  y <- my.func1(x)
  return(y)
}
```

When I run `my.func2(2)` I want to end up with `8` but R cannot evaluate it.

How should I design my second function `my.func2` so I can end up with the desired return value?

I know that I can let `my.func1` be a function of `x` *AND* `a` but I need `my.func1` to only be a function of `x`.

Comment: What is `a` inside my.func1?

Comment: this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38017085/4137985

Comment: @agerom, by the time I define define `my.func1` a is unknown. I define it later within `my.func2`

Comment: you mean `my.func2`?

Comment: @agerom , yes sorry for the typo, I corrected it

Comment: Sorry to be an arse, but this goes completely against the core of R. If you want your function to be useable, don't do this. Anyone can overwrite the temporary variable with eg a character value, and your function stops working. If you want to implement this inside a package, use environments to store "global" variables, but even that practice goes against R's philosophy.

Comment: @Joris Meys It might be "against R's philosophy" as you put but two answers were provided in here and both actually solve my problem :)

Comment: until I try it and set a <- "a" in the global environment. Then it creates a new one. Changing the enclosing environment of a function might be an option, but it's not foolproof either. If you do that eg in a package, you're in for some hard to trace bugs. Believe me, I've tried. Multiple times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem arises because a function maintains the environment in which it was created. Since my.func1 was created in the global environment, it can only look for objects in that environment (and parents of the environment if such exist in other cases).

Another alternative is to temporarily change the environment of my.func1 inside of my.func2. (you actually the environment of a copy of my.func1)

```
my.func2 <- function(x){
  # change environment of my.func1
  environment(my.func1) <- environment()
  a <- temp.variable
  y <- my.func1(x)
  return(y)
}
```

Then you get your desired result. In my opinion, this is preferable to global assignment, `<<-`, because it does not manipulate anything outside the function and so sticks closer to the tenets of functional programming.

```
my.func2(2)
[1] 8
```

Hadley's Advanced R provides a [lengthy discussion](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html) of this issue and related issues.

The ideal solution is to provide two arguments to my.func1, but since you specify that this is not possible, this is a fairly harmless work-around.

Answer (score 3):

Use `a <<- temp.variable` inside `my.func2`.  The `<<-` will make sure that the `a` is accessible in the global environment.

```
my.func1 <- function(x){a*x^2}

temp.variable <- 2

my.func2 <- function(x){
  a <<- temp.variable
  y <- my.func1(x)
  return(y)
}

my.func2(2)
[1] 8
```